# Can gzip change original file size?

Tags: dd, compression, gzip, sd-card, disk-image

`/dev/sdf` is a 32G SD.  As far as I can tell, I had performed the following, but upon attempting to perform the final step and write to a SD, my file image appears to be one byte to large for the SD.  Is there any change the compression image somehow increased the size of the original image?

```
#inserted first SD in SD Reader and successfully wrote image to file
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdf of=pibackup.img

#inserted second SD in SD Reader and successfully wrote image to SD
sudo dd bs=4M if=pibackup.img of=/dev/sdf

gzip pibackup.img
//Might have been moved back and forth between servers using `scp`
gzip -d pibackup.img.gz

#inserted third SD in SD Reader but am unsuccessful writing image to SD
sudo dd bs=4M if=pibackup.img of=/dev/sdf
```

By unsuccessful, I mean the following:
[Michael@devserver ~]$ sudo mount /dev/sdf7 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdf7,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

[Michael@devserver ~]$ dmesg | tail

```
DROP: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:78:24:af:ed:b7:58:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=343 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63614 PROTO=UDP SPT=67 DPT=68 LEN=323
DROP: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:b4:b5:2f:12:aa:fa:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=328 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=70 PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67 LEN=308
DROP: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:76:3f:69:31:95:78:24:af:ed:b7:58:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.140 LEN=328 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=12658 PROTO=UDP SPT=67 DPT=68 LEN=308
EXT4-fs (sdf5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
SELinux: initialized (dev sdf5, type ext4), uses xattr
EXT4-fs (sdf7): bad geometry: block count 7453824 exceeds size of device (7256064 blocks)
SELinux: initialized (dev sdf6, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sdf1, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
EXT4-fs (sdf7): bad geometry: block count 7453824 exceeds size of device (7256064 blocks)
EXT4-fs (sdf7): bad geometry: block count 7453824 exceeds size of device (7256064 blocks)
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

Comment: Can't you just run the first command again to fetch the image again from the first SD card and then compare? Normally I would consider it a severe bug if gzip is not able to recreate the original file as an identical copy. Are you sure the third SD card is big enough?

Comment: If not for any fault from outside, gzip followed by gunzip delivers exactly the original contents. The only thing I can think of, aside from hardware faults is an automatically added file terminator.

Comment: @Harald  The first SD is installed on a customer site.  The 3rd SD card is the same type that previously worked.  I think it is time for me to learn about shrinking partitions!

Comment: What do you mean by *unsuccessful writing image to SD*?  What error messages do you see?

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Please see edited initial post.

Comment: "The 3rd SD card is the same type.." - from the label printed on the card? Do not trust that. What does e.g. `fdisk` tell you about the size of the device (in bytes, sectors, ...)?